# hasura cli-migrations-v2 failed to apply metadata: cannot apply metadata on the database: [parse-failed] expected 1 or 2, encountered 0 ($[1].version)

Tags: graphql, hasura, database-metadata

I want to import the hasura metadata from CI/CD pipeline. I have tried using cli-migrations-v2 image. I am getting following error when it tries to import the metadata.

```
 ... level=fatal msg="failed to apply metadata: cannot apply metadata on the database: [parse-failed] expected 1 or 2, encountered 0 ($[1].version)"
```

The command I am using is as follows-

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --net=host --name=hasura-metadata-v2 -v /home/hasura_migrations/metadata:/hasura-metadata     -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://hasurauser:hasurauser@localhost:5432/new_db_migration        -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true   hasura/graphql-engine:v1.2.1.cli-migrations-v2
```

It is same as the one mentioned in the hasura documentation https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/migrations/advanced/auto-apply-migrations.html#auto-apply-migrations

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you upgraded your project to use config-v2, a `version.yaml` was created in `/home/hasura_migrations/metadata` path. The version in your file seems to be `0`. Just update it to `2` to use config-v2 and try again.

Expected content:

```
~$ cat /home/hasura_migrations/metadata/version.yaml
version: 2
```

It worked for me.